# Android: How to send an sms after an alarm ?

Tags: android, alarmmanager, smsmanager

my question is about an how to rather than a question of coding problem.

I am tryn to send an sms after a certain amount of time if the activity is not closed. To explain it more, for example we have an app. To begin with in this app user can define a message and a number to send. Also user can define an alarm. And what the app does is this ; When the alarm starts to count and if the user doesnt respond the alarm in a certain amount of time ( e.g. if the user doesn't hit the close button in 10 minute ) the app will send the sms to the predefined number.

So how can i do this ? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use cound Down timer and SMS manager. Basically when the count down timer ends send SMS in the onFinish() method. Please see the below pseudo-code. Hope this helps.

```
public class SMS {


    public static void send_SMS(String number, Context context, String name) {

        try {

            SmsManager smsManager = SmsManager.getDefault();

            smsManager.sendTextMessage(number, null, String);


        } catch (Exception e) {


        }

    }

}

public class pauseTimer extends CountDownTimer {

    public pauseTimer(long millisInFuture, long countDownInterval) {
        super(millisInFuture, countDownInterval);
    }

    @Override
    public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {

    }



    @Override
    public void onFinish() {
        object.send_SMS(number,getApplicationContext, name)
    }
}
```